# How to Remove Image Resizing Script from Blogger Template?

Tags: templates, themes, blogger, blogspot

I am using now Johny Demosite template. This theme using a cutter script which resizes all the image automatically in homepage. But the problem is it also increase the file size too. Like I upload a photo 15KB (500x400) then this script will convert it like s250-c (250x250) and make it like 25KB. Is there any way to remove this resizing script.

The code for the resizing script is -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
    function bp_thumbnail_resize(e,d){var c=280;var a=true;var b="<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>";if(a==true&&e==""){e=b}image_tag='<img src="'+e.replace("/s72-c/","/s"+c+"-c/")+'" class="postthumb" alt="'+d+'"/>';if(e!=""){return image_tag}else{return""}};
  //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the above script as follows -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
    function bp_thumbnail_resize(e,d){var c=280;var a=true;var b="<data:post.firstImageUrl/>";if(a==true&&e==""){e=b}image_tag='<img src="'+e+'" class="postthumb" alt="'+d+'"/>';if(e!=""){return image_tag}else{return""}};
  //]]>
</script>
```

The main difference in this script is that instead of using `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>` we are using `<data:post.firstImageUrl/>` . This new layout tags gets the first image from the post with its original resolution which is set at the time of uploading. Also, the other change is removing `.replace("/s72-c/","/s"+c+"-c/")` as we don't want to resize the image anymore